# get image hight and with in Titanium

Tags: android, iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

I need to get the hight and width of an image from a server that i need to show directly to the user.

so e have tried to create a imageView and put the image in it so i could read the hight and width of the imageView

```
var image = Ti.UI.createImageView({
                image : //host Site,
                width : "auto",
                height : "auto"
            });

var hight = image.height;
var width = image.width;
```

but it returns always hight = auto and width = auto.

how can i get the height and width like fro example hight = 630 and width = 320?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to get the hight and width of an image

```
 var image = Ti.UI.createImageView({
                image : //host Site,
                width : "auto",
                height : "auto"
            });

var hight = image.toBlob().height;
var width = image.toBlob().width;
```

i hade only to add toBolob() where i'm trying to get the height and width

Answer (score 1):

First, listen to the `load` or `postlayout` event : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ImageView-event-load
Instead this event, you can get the `Dimension` of the `ImageView` : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ImageView-method-getRect like this :

```
var rect = image.getRect();
```